# auto set value of a specific column after 24 hours and to delete record after one week: Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Here is my table:

```
create table passwordResetLink(
link_id number(5) primary key,
link_date timestamp(0) default sysdate NOT NULL,
isExpired number(2)
email varchar2(110) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
linkUsed number(2)
);
```

1. How can I auto update isExpired column? I mean when record is inserted its value should auto set to `0` and when 24 Hours passed the `0` should be updated as `1`
2. `link_date` is timestamp of inserted record. The record that has passed one week should auto be deleted from the table

Thanks

Comment: You have two good answers to your question, but please allow me to point out a couple of design flaws in your table.  First, you declare LINK_DATE as a TIMESTAMP, but then you initialize it with SYSDATE, which is a DATE not a TIMESTAMP.  No great harm, but it is an inconsistency that indicates a lack of understanding. Second, you declare ISEXPIRED as a 2-digit NUMBER.  Why?  It is a binary condition - true/false or yes/no.  Better as either a single digit number or a single character varchar2, either way with a check condition to limit it to one of two values.

Comment: @EdStevens when I said `link_date timestamp(0) NOT NULL,` then it says `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("schema"."PASSWORDRESETLINK"."LINK_DATE")` can you please be more specific what should I do with this date field?

Comment: who said anything about setting link_date for NOT NULL?  I simply pointed out the inconsistency of declaring it a TIMESTAMP, then initializing it with SYSDATE, which is a DATE, not a TIMESTAMP.  As for the error "ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into", that should be self-explanatory.  If you need help spotting how it is happening, you will need to post _formatted_ code of the relevant INSERT statement. But this error has nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: @EdStevens I still not understand. how I correct `link_date timestamp(0) default sysdate NOT NULL,`? can you please correct it

Comment: I would have thought that when I mentioned that SYSDATE returns a DATE not a TIMESTAMP, you might have gone to the docs to see if there was a similar function to return a TIMESTAMP.  Please see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SYSTIMESTAMP.html#GUID-FCED18CE-A875-4D5D-9178-3DE4FA956516

Comment: @EdStevens Thanks from the bottom of my heart. Its really a plus to my knowledge. I changed it like: `timestamp default systimestamp` instead of `timestamp(0) default sysdate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the "isexpired" column, don't store it as a literal column: use a view to determine that status dynamically. That way status is accurate to the second, at runtime.

```
create table passwordResetLink(
    link_id number(5) primary key,
    link_date timestamp(0) default sysdate NOT NULL,
    email varchar2(110) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    linkUsed number(2)
);

create or replace view passwordresetlink_view as
select link_id, 
       link_date,
       case when systimestamp > (link_date + interval '1' day)
            then 1
            else 0
       end isexpired,
       email,
       linkused 
from passwordresetlink;
```

For deletion of older records, use a scheduled job to run something like this:

```
delete from passwordresetlink where systimestamp > (link_date + interval '7' day);
```

Comment: Thanks all from the bottom of my heart

Answer (score 1):

Rather than query a table, why not query a view that has your rules built in?

```
CREATE VIEW vwPasswordResetLink
    AS 
SELECT link_id,
       link_date, 
       CASE WHEN sysdate > link_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END AS isExpired,
       email,
       linkUsed
  FROM PasswordResetLink 
 WHERE link_date >= sysdate - INTERVAL '7' DAY;
```

Then you can write a scheduled job to delete records older than 7 days to clear out expired records.

Alternatively, you could just use the above query to filter results and skip the creation of the view altogether …